# How to overlay a map and a scatterplot using ggplot? (see code)

Tags: r, ggplot2, graphics, data-visualization

I made a scatterplot using data on `longitude` and `latitude` in order to display the location of schools of different educational levels for a region in Mexico. Here's the code to replicate:

(Note: I don't show maps for saving space purposes but you can see them just copying, pasting and running in your R session)

```
library(foreach)
library(forcats)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(raster)
library(readr)
library(reshape2)
##Load csv file
gto<- read_csv(sprintf("http://fs.planeacion.sep.gob.mx/cct/cct11.csv"))

##Educational levels (this is how levels are ordered from min to max)
nivel_ed <- c("Primaria", "Secundaria", "Bachillerato", "Superior")

##Plot
    gtomap <- subset(gto, select=c(longitud, latitud, nnivel)) %>%
        filter(nnivel%in%c("PRIMARIA", "SECUNDARIA", "BACHILLERATO", 
        "PEDAGOGICA, UNIVERSITARIA O TECNOLOGICA", "PROFESIONAL")) %>%
        mutate(nnivel= case_when(nnivel== "PEDAGOGICA, UNIVERSITARIA O TECNOLOGICA" ~ "Superior",
            nnivel=="PROFESIONAL" ~ "Superior", 
            nnivel=="SECUNDARIA" ~ "Secundaria",
            nnivel=="PRIMARIA" ~ "Primaria",
            nnivel=="BACHILLERATO" ~ "Bachillerato")) %>% 
        mutate(nnivel= factor(nnivel, levels=nivel_ed)) %>%
        melt(id =c("longitud","latitud"))  %>% 
        mutate(value= factor(value, levels=nivel_ed)) %>%
        ggplot(aes(x = longitud, y = latitud, col= value)) +
        geom_point() +
        theme(legend.title=element_blank()) +
        labs(x = "", y="")

    gtomap ##To see the scatterplot
```

Secondly, I download the dev version of ggplot in order to use `geom_sf` function

```
devtools::install_github("tidyverse/ggplot2")
```

Thirdly, I download a map

```
mapgto <- sf::read_sf("http://geoinfo.iplaneg.net/geoserver/wms/kml?layers=geonode%3Amgm_gto2010&mode=download", quiet=T)
map <- data.frame(mapgto)
```

Map can be called directly with:

```
ggplot() + 
geom_sf(data=map)
```

Now, I tried to overlay these objects using:

```
gtomap + geom_sf(data=map)
```

But this error is thrown:

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'longitud' not found
```

I tried many other combinations using `geom_sf` with no satisfactory results. Any advice and orientation will be much appreciated.

Comment: you might need an `inherit.aes = FALSE` in the `geom_sf`

Comment: This is not a complete reproducible example. Please include all `library()` calls necessary. Try testing it in a fresh R session to see if it is reproducible

Comment: @loki Thanks for your comment. I've just made an edition.

Comment: I might suggest you look into the ggmap package.

Comment: @RichardTelford I tried your suggestion and didn't work. Thank you anyway.